# CusotomSwitch draw as Button

Tags: android, android-widget

I'm writing a CustomSwitch. It is extended from [Switch](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Switch.html). Under some circumstances in the `onDraw()` method, I want to draw the CustomSwitch as a Button.

I tried several approaches, but neither did work. I can't call `((Button)this).draw(canvas);` in the `onDraw()` cause thats going to result in a stack overflow.
I tried to clone the CustomSwitch or inflate it and cast it to Button, but nether of those two approaches did work, too.

Does any body have another idea how I can draw a CustomSwitch as Button?

Comment: CustomSwitch is extended from View?

Comment: CustomSwitch is extended from [Switch](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Switch.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, here is what I did.

```
private Button drawButton;
public CustomSwitch(Context context) {
    super(context);
    this.drawButton = new Button(context);
}
public CustomSwitch(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    this.drawButton = new Button(context, attrs);
}
public CustomSwitch(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    this.drawButton = new Button(context, attrs, defStyle);
}
@Override
public void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    this.drawButton.measure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
};
@Override
protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
    super.onLayout(changed, left, top, right, bottom);
    this.drawButton.layout(left, top, right, bottom);
};
@Override
protected void onDraw(android.graphics.Canvas canvas) {
    //...
    if(condition) {
        this.drawButton.draw(canvas);
    }
}
```